# What to use as the keypath in KVO?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, view, key-value-observing

I have a view controller with a view that changes (for example), and I would like to observe the frame of any view that self.view is set to.
Is there any difference between:

```
[self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:nil];
```

and

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"view.frame" options:0 context:nil];
```

For the second one, if the view changes will messages still be recieved when the new view's frame changes, or will it only send messages if the frame of the view that was set when the observer was added?

Is there any way to observe changes to the frame property even if the view of the view controller changes after adding the observer?

Answer (score 7):

Use the second path. `@"view.frame"` will notify you about the frame changes even when the "view" itself is changed. Cocoa will add observers for every object in the keyPath "chain" for you automatically (which means *every item* in the keyPath must be KVO-compatible).

Comment: Yea, the true, almighty power of KVO was revealed!

Answer (score 2):

You asked if there is a difference between the two, The answer is yes, there is a difference between them:

**The first one**

says "me as a view", I add an observer named self (aka) viewControllerObject, if you invoked this in viewController.m  whenever my property named "frame" is changed.

**The Second one**

Says "me as ViewController" I'm adding myselfAsAnObserver whenever theKeyPath named "view.frame" is changed.

Since every observer should implement

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                     ofObject:(id)object 
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                      context:(void *)context
```

For this case you won't notice much difference because you added a viewController as an observer in either of the method above, but it will make a difference when you are dealing with different objects. But the rule is simple, each added observer should implement the

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                     ofObject:(id)object 
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                      context:(void *)context
```

One more thing: 
Its a good idea to create a context for observation 
e.g

```
//In MyViewController.m 

//.. 
static int observingViewFrameContext


// In ...
[self addObserver:self 
       forKeyPath:@"view.frame" 
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld 
          context:&observingViewFrameContext];


// .. don' forget to remove an observer ! too
```